# RBAC Routes add default route of module to all the routes of project?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-user

If I add this configuration of the `cms` module to the config file

```
'cms' => [
        'class' => 'yii2mod\cms\Module',
        'controllerNamespace' => 'backend\controllers',
        'defaultRoute' => '',
        'froalaEditorOptions' => [
            'clientOptions' => [
                'heightMin' => 300,
                'theme' => 'dark',
                'imageUploadURL' => 'upload-image',
                'imageManagerDeleteURL' => 'delete-image',
                'imageManagerDeleteMethod' => 'POST',
                'imageManagerLoadURL' => 'images'
            ],
            'excludedPlugins' => [
                'file',
                'emoticons'
            ]
        ],
        'enableMarkdown' => false
]
```

It adds the default route of this module to all the routes like this
`/cms/site/login` `/cms/site/index` `/cms/site/error`. Why this is happening and how i can remove this?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam

Comment: I don't get what you are asking here, please add your complete configurations file and also if you are using `advance` or `basic` app.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam if i open routes in rbac  i need there like  /site/login  /site/signup etc , all the routes need to start with there controller.this is happen when i add the cms module in config file.The routes dosent add cms in the routes like /cms/site/login when i remove the cms module from config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the /cms module prefix by default, you can add a global route to `backend/config/main.php`(If you use advanced templates): `'<controller:[\w-]+>/<action:[\w-]+>' =>'cms/<controller>/<action>'`.

for example:

```
// backend/config/main.php
return [
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '<controller:[\w-]+>/<action:[\w-]+>' =>'cms/<controller>/<action>'
        ],
    ],
];
```

Access in your bowser: `www.xxx.com/site/index`, it is forwarded to: `/cms/site/index`

Comment: great thats work fine.Please upwote the answer if you feel good enough.